# NetSuite - line item loop issue

Tags: javascript, json, netsuite

I'm struggling to see why this loop will not work properly. It seems it only iterates the first time round only. The line item count logs 4 so should loop 4 times since there are 4 line items. Need to be able to update line items from external system so I have an external id which i am matching against existing external ids.

```js
var itemcount = update_record.getLineItemCount('item');
for (var i = 1; i <= itemcount; i++)
{
 var a_id = update_record.getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_ex_line_id', i);
 var json_itemcount = jsonObject.item.length
 for (var x = 0; json_itemcount != null && x < json_itemcount; x++)
 {
  var json_id = jsonObject.item[x].ex_line_id
  if(json_id == a_id)
  {
   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Match Found');
   update_record.setLineItemValue('item', 'amount', i, jsonObject.item[x].amount)
   var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(update_record, true);
   return id;
  }
  else
  {
   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'no match found - no updates required');
  }
 }
}



"item": [{"item" : 38, "amount": 1786, "ex_line_id" : 111},
         {"item" : 38, "amount": 1786, "ex_line_id" : 113},
]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code stops because the first time it updates the underlying record and returns.

You want to do your updates in the loops but not submit the record and return until the loops finish.

Comment: Grrr, sorry but found an issue. Where I have the else - I was going to create new line items if the json_id is not matched against the a_id. But I only want it to hit else, if after all the comparison is done and there is no match. Right now as soon as the first comparison is done and no match is found it hits else...but that json_id might exist after few line itmes